# Get Google Project ID from Client ID + Secret?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I've got a Client ID and Client Secret for some Google-based authentication in a Django app. How do I use this information to get the actual Google project name/ID that is being used?

Using an API would be great but I'm down for clicking through a bit of web UI too.

P.S. -- I am unsure how to tag/categorize this question so I appreciate any help there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My co-worker pointed out the obvious answer. Here's an example client ID:

```
GOOGLEAUTH_CLIENT_ID=1234567890-aksjfljsalfjslfjlksf.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

The digits preceding the first hyphen *are* the Google Cloud Project Number. *Voila!* No API call required. **face smash**

The Number can be used to look up the ID using `gcloud projects list`:

```
PROJECT_ID             NAME       PROJECT_NUMBER
example-river-417      Example    1234567890
asdfjkl                Example2   1234567891
```

Comment: The first digits are the `Project Number` and not the `Project ID`. They are directly related to each other. The command `gcloud projects list` will show these values.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, I've updated the answer to differentiate the Number from the ID